# Extracting information from external websites

Tags: php, symfony

I have a couple of websites from which I want to extract some information of similar nature (like product feed). If I had the whole DOM of those websites, I could write an algorithm doing this to some extent.

Is this possible without selenium? If not, can I use selenium itself to do that, without PHPUnit?

Comment: Unless they're loading content in with JS / AJAX, you can just use file_get_contents / cURL to get the markup, then use an HTML parser to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) or [Zombie.js](https://github.com/assaf/zombie). There is a lot of tools. PHPUnit is not required.